# grant create view in Sybase IQ

Tags: database, sql-grant, sap-iq, create-view

i'm trying granting a group to create view in `Sybase IQ` :

```
grant create view to groupname
```

it show error :

```
error near 'create' on line 1
```

how to do it?

Comment: What version of Sybase IQ are you using? This statement is only supported in version 16.x.

Comment: Hi @GraemePerrow it still using 12.7.0. so its not posible to grant ONLY create view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the version you are using, you cannot grant *only* the ability to create a view. The permissions structure was must less granular until version 16, so you will need to grant resource authority to the user/group using `grant resource to groupname`.